# Android Studio file upload question (retrofit multipartbody)

Tags: android, file-upload, retrofit2

I am trying to implement retrofit2 file upload as a multipartbody, but it seems that Android Studio can't upload php files or can't pass the files to send.

Api

```
@Multipart
@POST("upload_img.php")
Call<ResultModel> upload_img(@Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

Main.java

```
MultipartBody.Part body = null;
File file = new File(img_url);
RequestBody fileReqBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
RequestBody fileName = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file.getName());
MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("uploaded_file", file.getName(), fileReqBody);
Call<ResultModel> call2 = userApi.upload_img(filePart);

call2.enqueue(new Callback<ResultModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResultModel> call, Response<ResultModel> response){
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResultModel> call, Throwable t) {
    }
});
```

Comment: `But it seems that Android studio can't upload.....` ? I think your Android app is trying to upload. Not Android Studio.

Comment: Can you show me? The php code you used and the path of the img_url in "File file = new File(img_url);"?

Comment: I am using it like this.

Comment: <?php
$uploaddir = "./";
$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    $result =array("result" => "success");
} else{
    $result = array("result" => "error");
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>